# how to display sum of field in axgridview

Tags: user-controls, sum, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm working with Microsoft Dynamics AX R3,2012 and i want to add a group by field in an dynamics:AxGridView  then a sum for a certain field by the group field indicated then the total sum  without the group by .Please help me .i didn't find a solution.like what described in this page http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply,My Problem is not to create display method  but the Problem is how to display the sum of subtotal by this display field.So my solution is to add GroupField in the AxGridView with designed field like GoalId in my case.then in the AxGridView i create template field with footer containing label not visible in default. So in rowdatabound i do the total by the new group that known with a test in rowcreated in GoalId 's value changes .Then when i get a new group i put the value of cumul of the previous value of a the previous group and in the footer template i display the total of all rows.this is the solution and thanks so much for your help. but now the problem that i noticed that axgridview have problems after updating data with a groupby fields and with template field.it display noting in this fields

Answer (score 1):

You can create a display method to compute your sum on each row. If you do so, don't forget the 'cacheAddMethod' in order not to compute it each time. This is the "historical" way.
More info on [display methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx).

Or you can create a view and use computed column in it. It will depends on your current datamodel and query you want to run.
More info on [computed column in views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845841.aspx).

Comment: Hi,please give me an example.your suggestion is not clear .How by display method add a row that describe the sum of every group.the axgridview not only on mode readonly.It's can be updated

Comment: Creating a display method in a table, you can add this one to your grid like a field. As you can set 'AllowEdit=No' on a field , the display  keyword in method prototype will prevent any modification even the grid is in edit mode.
Creating the method on the table, the record context is handled by the system.

Creating the display method on the datasource of your form, you will have to add the record context. instead, the all column will display the value for the current selected record.

It's a best practice to create display method in tables. In forms it's only if the form context is needed.

Comment: You can look at table method SalesTable.amountInvoiced() for an example.